# Showing that Derivative is Linear

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, functions, derivatives

Question is: In $$f(a+h) - f(a) = h f'(a + \frac h 2), \qquad a, h \in \mathbb R$$ show $f'$ is  line.

I have no problems with the first part.  I'm however having trouble with taking the derivative to h and concluding that f' must be line.

First all I'm not sure if I even got the derivative correct, but this is what I got:
Derivative:
$f'(a+h)=f'(a+h/2) +(h/2)*f''(a+h/2)$.

Comment: The statement is true under differentiability assumption only. For the proof see my blog. Unfortulately in polish but maths is universal, so I think it is not difficult to decipher.

http://byc-matematykiem.pl/trojmiany-kwadratowe-a-twierdzenie-lagrangea/

Comment: Rename $h = 2y$ and insert $a = -y$. You get $f'(y) = \dotsc$.

Comment: f'(y)=f'(0)+yf''(0)

Comment: so I get f'(y)=f'(0)+y''f(0)

Answer (score 0):

As your derivation shows you have

$$2f'(a+h) - 2f'(a+h/2) = hf''(a+h/2)$$

since $a$ and $h$ is arbitrary we have that

$$f'(x) - f'(y) = (x-y) f''(y)$$

but also by derivate with respect to $a$ you have

$$f'(a+h) - f'(a) = h f''(a+h/2)$$

again $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary so we have

$$f'(x) - f'(y) = (x-y)f''\left({x+y\over2}\right)$$

Combining these two we get since the LHS is the same we get

$$(x-y) f''(x) = (x-y)f''\left({x+y\over2}\right)$$

which only holds generally if $f''$ is constant, but $f''$ being constant means that there's a constant $A$ such that $0=f''(x)-2A = {d\over dx}(f'(x)-2Ax))$, so $f'(x)-2Ax$ is constant which means there's a constant $B$ such that $0=f'(x) - 2Ax - B = {d\over dx}(f(x) - Ax^2 - Bx)$ so $f(x) - Ax^2 - Bx$ is constant which means that there's a $C$ such that $f(x)=Ax^2+Bx+C$.

Comment: I have h/2 though not h.

Comment: Also, one fundamental thing I don't understand is how does showing f' must be linear prove that quadratic functions are the only twice differentiable functions.

Comment: @kemb Since $h$ is arbitrary you can have $h$ too. That $f'$ is linear prove that it's quadratic follows from the general solution to differential equation which in turn follows from MVT.

Comment: Ok makes sense.  So going to my second question:how does showing f' must be linear prove that quadratic functions are the only twice differentiable functions?

Comment: @kemb I've added a proof for that too - it follows from the fact that a function with vanishing derivate must be constant (of course this requires it to be everywhere differentiable). That it has to be constant follows from MVT since otherwise we could get a sloping secant and thereby somewhere finding a non-zero derivate.

Comment: Makes sense.  Although I just realized, I am slightly confused.  How did you get f'''(x)=0, I thought it should be f''(x)=0?

Comment: @kemb Thanks for being critical. Thanks to that I found an issue with my proof, I had actually assumed that $f$ was thrice derivable which wasn't given. Instead one need to prove directly that $f''$ is constant or that $f'$ is a line (I changed the proof to the later).

Comment: @kemb I changed to what I think is a bit simplier proof.

Comment: Great so we have f'' is constant and f' is thus linear.  So how does this show that quadratic functions are the only twice differentiable functions?

Comment: What happens if we just apply the Mean Value Theorem to the derivative?

Comment: $f'(a+h)=f'(a+h/2) +(h/2)*f''(a+h/2)$.  $f'(a+h)-f'(a+h/2)/(h/2)$=$f''(a+h/2).%

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68064/discussion-between-skyking-and-kemb).